# Bootstrap 4.1 carousel-indicators

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using last version for bootstrap 4.1

I'm trying to use carousel indicators.

but when I try to press on one of my indicators.

it's not working.

I don't want to use the:
"carousel-control-prev"
"carousel-control-nextx"

Here is my Code:

```
<section class="slider">
    <div id="sitebanners" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#sitebanners" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#sitebanners" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#sitebanners" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="First slide"/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h5 class="title">get your stylish</h5>
                    <h5 class="sub_title">look today</h5>
                    <p>Make your hairstyle an important part for the expression of your identity! Our licensed hair
                        dressers will make sure you get the exact style you want!</p>
                    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="Second slide"/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h5 class="title">premier esthetics</h5>
                    <h5 class="sub_title">services</h5>
                    <p>Premier Esthetics offers various treatments to enhance the natural beauty of your skin while
                        targeting areas of concern to achieve optimal results.</p>
                    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/banner3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Third slide"/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h5 class="title">ultimate experience</h5>
                    <h5 class="sub_title">in hair care</h5>
                    <p>Highlights are always trendy! From just a Sun Kiss to Platinum Blonde we can transform the way
                        your hair looks and make it shiny!</p>
                    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I try to many ways.

but nothing works

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. I added some padding around the wrapper and gave it a dark background, but otherwise it's the same as your code. The example below shows it working, so there must be something else, elsewhere in your code that is interfering with your indicator functions.

Don't want to sound facetious, but have you included the Bootstrap JS files?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); padding: 30px;">

  <section class="slider">
    <div id="sitebanners" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#sitebanners" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#sitebanners" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#sitebanners" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="First slide" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h5 class="title">get your stylish</h5>
            <h5 class="sub_title">look today</h5>
            <p>Make your hairstyle an important part for the expression of your identity! Our licensed hair dressers will make sure you get the exact style you want!</p>
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="Second slide" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h5 class="title">premier esthetics</h5>
            <h5 class="sub_title">services</h5>
            <p>Premier Esthetics offers various treatments to enhance the natural beauty of your skin while targeting areas of concern to achieve optimal results.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="images/banner3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Third slide" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h5 class="title">ultimate experience</h5>
            <h5 class="sub_title">in hair care</h5>
            <p>Highlights are always trendy! From just a Sun Kiss to Platinum Blonde we can transform the way your hair looks and make it shiny!</p>
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yes , also I’m using bootstrap 4.1

Comment: I have also found lots of weirdness with bootstrap 4.1